# Question on sigma additivity on an algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am confused about a problem.
Would you help me to figure it out?

$\Omega$ is uncountable. $F_o$=$\{A\in \Omega | A\; or\; A^c \;is\; finite\}$ is an algebra.

For $E\in F_o$, let $P$ be a set function such that

$P(E)=0$ if $E$ is finite, $P(E)=1$ if $E^C$ is finite.

Show $P$ is sigma-additive on $F_o$.

My major concern is that $\cup^\infty_{n=1}A_n$ might not be in $F_o$ where $A_n\in F_o$ for every $n\in{N}$, so that I cannot define the function $P$ in this case. Is there a reason $\cup^\infty_{n=1}A_n$ should belong to $F_o$?

Comment: Being sigma-additive on an algebra $F$ means that, for every disjoint sequence $(A_n)$ in $F$ **such that the union $A=\bigcup\limits_nA_n$ is in $F$** then $P(A)=\sum\limits_nP(A_n)$. Hence your "major concern" is moot.

Comment: @Did: Would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: Your algebra has the property that there is not a partition of $\Omega$ into a countable family of pairwise disjoint non-empty elements of  this algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being sigma-additive on an algebra $F$ means that, for every disjoint sequence $(A_n)$ in $F$ **such that the union $A=\bigcup\limits_nA_n$ is in $F$** then $P(A)=\sum\limits_nP(A_n)$. Hence your "major concern" is moot.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. It helps me a lot.